# Characters in a batch file string variable

Tags: batch-file, powershell

How can I add characters such as ';' ,'+', '=' into a string variable in a batch file?

Basically I am writing a batch file to write the psmodulepath of Powershell.

```
set "VAR=$env:PSmodulepath=$env:PSmodulepath+;C:\Powershellscripts\modules"

PowerShell.exe %VAR%

pause
```

I know this above code wont do me any good but I just want to understand how to pass the string correctly. When I run the batch file, I get the error as below
:

```
C:\Users\Kiran_Vasanth\Desktop\Powe>PowerShell.exe $env:PSmodulepath=$env:PSmodu
lepath+;C:\Powershellscripts\modules
At line:1 char:37
+ $env:PSmodulepath=$env:PSmodulepath+;C:\Powershellscripts\modules
+                                     ~
You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Any help?

Comment: nope. This gives the correct string i want to pass to powershell: set "VAR=$env:PSmodulepath^ =^ $env:PSmodulepath^+^ ^";C:\Powershellscripts\modules^"" However, I get a "Must provide a value expression following the '+' operator" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the powershell.The `+` and `=` are set to the variable . test with 
`echo "%VAR%"` . Just powershell starts to execute this as a command.

May be you want this?

```
set "VAR=$env:PSmodulepath=$env:PSmodulepath+;C:\Powershellscripts\modules"

PowerShell.exe """%VAR%"""
```

Comment: Thank you. This does the job. It was a silly problem I had and now i have decided to directly write a powershell script and use the batch file to call this PS script:)